# Insert section into XML document

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SyncSupplierInvoice xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" languageCode="en-US" releaseID="9.2" systemEnvironmentCode="Production" versionID="2.8.0">
    <UserArea>
        <Property>
            <NameValue name="TypeCode">PS</NameValue>
        </Property>
        <Property>
            <NameValue name="TaxCode">TGPLG180</NameValue>
        </Property>
        <Property>
            <NameValue name="TaxOrg">*</NameValue>
        </Property>
    </UserArea>
</SyncSupplierInvoice>
```

There are **3 Property** sections in the UserArea. I want to insert a 4th section, **customTaxCode**, which contains last character of the TaxCode. Like so:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SyncSupplierInvoice xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" languageCode="en-US" releaseID="9.2" systemEnvironmentCode="Production" versionID="2.8.0">
    <UserArea>
        <Property>
            <NameValue name="TypeCode">PS</NameValue>
        </Property>
        <Property>
            <NameValue name="TaxCode">TGPLG180</NameValue>
        </Property>
        <Property>
            <NameValue name="customTaxCode">0</NameValue>
        </Property>
        <Property>
            <NameValue name="TaxOrg">*</NameValue>
        </Property>
    </UserArea>
</SyncSupplierInvoice>
```

My XSLT is only working partially. The problem is that it creates the Property elements under the existing Property element, rather than as a sibling. I am not sure how to achieve the result. Thank you in advance for any advice.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:my="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2" xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java" exclude-result-prefixes="java">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />   
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="//my:UserArea/my:Property/my:NameValue[@name='TaxCode']">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <Property>
        <NameValue name="customTaxCode">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(., string-length(.), 1)" />
        </NameValue>
    </Property>
   </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of your template matching `my:NameValue`, change it to match the relevant `my:Property` instead.

```
<xsl:template match="//my:UserArea/my:Property[my:NameValue/@name='TaxCode']">
```

Or, better still, this, as starting a template match with `//` is unnecessary.

```
<xsl:template match="my:Property[my:NameValue/@name='TaxCode']">
```

Note that you should also add a default namespace declaration to your XSLT to ensure the new `Property` element you create is in the same namespace as the source

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                            xmlns:my="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2" 
                            xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2"
                            xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java" 
                            exclude-result-prefixes="my java">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="my:Property[my:NameValue/@name='TaxCode']">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <Property>
        <NameValue name="customTaxCode">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(my:NameValue, string-length(my:NameValue), 1)" />
        </NameValue>
    </Property>
   </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<xsl:template match="//my:UserArea/my:Property[my:NameValue[@name='TaxCode']]">
```

Issue is occured due to you use it as NameValue lavel